# Exporting a database to .sql Flat file using SQL SERVER 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I would like to export certain tables of the database to a .sql flat file using SQL Server 2012.

I went to SQL SERVER Management Studio -> Right Clicked on the database I would like to export -> Task -> Export Data

Then I landed on this page

[image]

Then I created a filename, Entered " for a Text qualifier

Then I clicked the next button and landed on this screen.

[image]

I am unable to continue from here due to the following error:

> Columns are not defined for this connection manager.

Comment: You don't want to use 'Flat File Source' as your data source, you want to use SQL Server as your source. Change this and try again.

Comment: See if this is easier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884965/generate-script-for-both-schema-and-data

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid its definitely much easier.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I would like to include the data as well

Comment: When you "Change “Script Data” option to true" as per the link it should export the data as INSERT statements