# Reduce size of SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-backups

I have a database with 20GB space. I have taken the backup and want to restore it to 3 other databases. But due to large size of database, it's prompting low space message on restore.I don't want all the data. Is there any way to reduce size of database OR what are the possible ways to manage all this work?

Previously, I took a backup and shrink it. The size was reduced to 1.11GB but on restoring back with a new database name, it takes 20GB disk space again.

Comment: I think u can get the schema script by going into tasks then to get only schema

Comment: Do you mean to generate database script without data ?

Comment: yes you are correct you can generateonly schema

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate script for both schema and data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884965/generate-script-for-both-schema-and-data)

Answer (score 2):

Generate Script and type of script make as schema only and create new database and run this script...