# SQL (Server): Copy query result in existing table with structure of query result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have created an SQL query that merges duplicates in a table:

```
SELECT Min([XNbr]) AS [XNbr], [ZNbr], [Hamster], [Cat], [Cow], [Dog],
[Squirrel], [Bird], [Mouse], [Flower], [Tree], Max([TimeStamp]) AS
[TimeStamp]
FROM dbo.Sunshine
GROUP BY [ZNbr], [Hamster], [Cat], [Cow], [Dog], [Squirrel], [Bird],
[Mouse], [Flower], [Tree]
ORDER BY [XNbr]
```

I now want to extend this query to transfer the result in target table I created before that has the exact structure (same fields and types) of the query above. How can that be done?

Comment: What's wrong with simply `INSERT`?

Comment: To create the table on the fly use `SELECT` `INTO`. To insert into an existing table, use `INSERT` `SELECT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need just `INSERT INTO` :

```
INSERT INTO TargetTable (Columns)
SELECT Min([XNbr]) AS [XNbr], [ZNbr], [Hamster], [Cat], [Cow], [Dog],
[Squirrel], [Bird], [Mouse], [Flower], [Tree], Max([TimeStamp]) AS
[TimeStamp]
FROM dbo.Sunshine
GROUP BY [ZNbr], [Hamster], [Cat], [Cow], [Dog], [Squirrel], [Bird],
[Mouse], [Flower], [Tree]
ORDER BY [XNbr]
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the result temporarily in the table.

Use 'generate scrips' option in the sql server and chose the table created.

[Generate script for both schema and data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884965/generate-script-for-both-schema-and-data)

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/26b237/generate-database-script-in-sql-server-2012/

After generating the script, just change the table name.

Or

If the target table doesn't exist in the database then,

```
 SELECT Min([XNbr]) AS [XNbr], [ZNbr], [Hamster], [Cat], [Cow], [Dog], [Squirrel], [Bird], [Mouse], [Flower], [Tree], Max([TimeStamp]) AS [TimeStamp]                                     
 into TargetTable 
 FROM dbo.Sunshine 
 GROUP BY [ZNbr], [Hamster], [Cat], [Cow], [Dog], [Squirrel], [Bird], [Mouse], [Flower], [Tree] 
 ORDER BY [XNbr]
```

The generated table will have the same schema as the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Insert Into Select Syntax. Visit this link to refer more: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp